# Multi-targeting .NET assembly to use async/await on .NET 4.5 and .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, async-await, csproj

I am currently trying to build a small portable library for which I need to use async/await.
My goal is that I want to be able to use my library on both the .NET 4, as well as the .NET 4.5 runtime. Ideally I would like to use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async pack when targeting .NET 4, whereas for .NET 4.5 I want to use the built-in async/await support without including the Bcl pack.

That said, I would like to have the bcl.async dll excluded from my project when compiling to .NET 4.5, as this gives me warnings about ambigous references between the built-in async of C# 5 in .NET 4.5 and the bcl.async pack.

Is this possible, if so how, else what would be a better way of going about this problem?

Comment: Do you wish to compile the library under .net 4.0 or .net 4.5 ? how do you determine what function to run ?

Comment: Are you saying that if you have a PCL that references Bcl.Async and a .Net 4.5 application that references that library, you're getting the warnings?

Comment: @ilansch: I wish to compile my library to both .net 4.0 as well as 4.5. What I basically want is to make sure that my .net 4.0 version includes and references the bcl.async library, whereas the .net 4.5 version should not, since the functionality is already included in the framework.

Comment: @svick: No, rather that I've tried to set my pcl to compile to .net 4.0, whilst referencing the bcl.async library, but when I compile to .net 4.5, the compiler complains about having both the async coming from the bcl.async library as well as the one from the framework itself.

Comment: The point of PCL is that you set it to target *both* .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5. If you do that, you will be use the same assembly from both.

Comment: I think what @svick means to say is - why are you compiling the library separately for .NET 4.0 and 4.5? When you compile it for .NET 4.0, it is also compatible with 4.5. Could you clarify why you need to compile separately?

Comment: What errors are you getting with a .NET 4.5 project with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` installed? I'm not seeing any.

Comment: @StephenCleary: I've just experimented with it, and it seems that I don't get any warnings or errors if I create a PCL which supports .net 4.5 and add the microsoft.bcl.async pack. However, if I create a PCL that supports .net 4.0, add the async pack and that change the PCL to target .net 4.5, then I get errors about duplicate identifies for System.Threading.Tasks and System.Runtime.

Comment: @YK1: Valid point, and this is also here I am not sure if I am actually doing the right thing - considering what I want to accomplish in the end. So basically I have my .net 4.5 library up and running, but I wish to make it support .net 4.0 as well. In order to do so, the only way I can see this is possible is to use the bcl.async package. I am not sure whether I should re-target my current .net 4.5 PCL to 4.0, or if I should (if possible), build two versions of my PCL, whereas the .net 4.0 version includes the bcl.async pack and the .net 4.5 version just uses the framework directly.

Comment: @SørenEngel: That's normal, and is an unfortunate side effect of how NuGet interacts with PCLs. If you change your PCL targets, you should uninstall all NuGet packages first, change the targets, and then re-install them. I recommend you just target .NET 4.0 with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the answer from @StephenCleary, whereas I targeted my PCL to .NET 4.0, and used the Bcl.Async pack.

Thanks!

Comment: So running on a platform having .Net 4.5 installed you ignore its advantages continuing run on 4.0 + Bcl crutch, do you?